# Posting dynamic data to twitter

Tags: c#, javascript, twitter

I'm aware that you can post data to twitter

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
<div>
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
    data-url="http://bit.ly/twitter-api-announce"
    data-counturl="http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce"
    data-text="Checking out this page about Tweet Buttons"
</div>
```

But is there a way to populate the data-text dynamically. For example set the value depending on an `asp:Label` text.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in your ASPX page:

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
<div>
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
    data-url="http://bit.ly/twitter-api-announce"
    data-counturl="http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce"
    data-text='<%= "Insert your variable here" %>'
</div>
```

Note the `"Insert your variable here"` string; replace that with a variable that will produce a string and that will be rendered to your page.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a static piece of code but you probably using it in an aspx application, of course you must be able to change the value dynamically. It's almost the same as filling a label or a textbox.